# Regarding POST and Delete on same record from database using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to test Post and delete APIs through JMeter. The post will have request data and the same request data can be used in Delete as well. Here is what I did:

1. Created a CSV file and used the CSV Data Set Config for reading variable names from CSV file.
   My CSV file has 5 records and my POST request will sue this data and post the data to the database.
2. I need to send POST request and then followed by delete request for the same record to post and delete every time for 5 records from CSV file.

Issue:
When I set threads to 10 and Loopcount to either 1, 2,3 it worked. But when set "Specify thread lifetime" its started failing due to deleting is trying to delete the record before POSTing to DB. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have 10 threads and only 5 items in the CSV file when you increase the number of iterations you're getting 10 concurrent users which are running into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so one user is trying to delete a record which hasn't been yet created and another one may be creating a record which exists already.

So you need to either reduce the number of threads to 5 or add 5 more rows to your CSV file.

Another option would be [creating the test data "on the fly"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create-test-data-in-a-database-with-jmeter) depending on the number of threads you're going to be using for your tests. Data creation can happen in [setUp Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)